# Can't call javascript alert alertify library from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, alert, alertify

I am using javascript alertify library for customized alerts.

When I call alertify from javascript everything is ok, but, If I do It from PHP doesnt works. THe error say "Alertify is not defined".

Is important to say that If I use default javascript alerts It works from PHP.

Why is happing this?

Regards

UPDATE:

```
  // This works
  if(empty($user_password)){ 
     echo "<script>alert('Por favor, ingrese su usuario y contraseña');</script>";
  }


  // This doesnt works
  if(empty($user_password)){ 
     echo "<script>alertify.alert('Por favor, ingrese su usuario y contraseña');</script>";
  }
  // Alertify library is included
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client-side code and server-side code.

Comment: I know it but why the default alert works and customized alertify not?

Comment: You probably ran that before defining the function.

Comment: Probably the `alertify.alert` is processed before the `alertify` library is included by the browser. So you'd have to do it in some other way. E.g. through an ajax request

Comment: What does your HTML look like as it is rendered by the web browser?

Comment: Thanks AmazingDreams, It solved by you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the lib isn't ready yet, try:

```
if(empty($user_password)){ 
     echo "<script>$(function(){alertify.alert('Por favor, ingrese su usuario y contraseña');})</script>";
  }
```

Comment: It say "$ is not defined "

Comment: Ok, need more info. Are you using jQuery? If not my code won't work, but you must be sure that you run that code in your page after the alertify inclusion. Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Use onload event on js|jquery to trigger alertify.
Use sessions to store feedback detail and check if sessions are set before echoed.

```
<?php

//partial php code

if($saveData)
{
$_SESSION['variable'] = 'text here';
header('location:link.php');
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link href="path/alertify.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["variable"])):?>
    
    <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            alertify.alert("Title", "<?=$_SESSION["variable"]?>");
        }
    </script>
    
    <?php unset($_SESSION["variable"]); endif;?>
    
    <script src="path/alertify.js"></script>
</body>
```